# Blackberry Emulator under Windows to test website

Tags: blackberry, emulation

I am going to be developing a web version of a website in .NET and would like to test it out as it would appear on a Blackberry.  Is there an emulator for Windows that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BlackBerry Simulator](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/simulators.jsp)

You will also need an [MDS services simulator](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/devtoolsdownloads.jsp) to connect to internet with your simulator

Answer (score 2):

You can download [emulators](https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477) or a [VS plugin](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/devbetasoftware/eclipseplugin.jsp) from Blackberry.  I used one of the emulators three or four years ago on a project and it worked fine, no experience with the plugin.